# Error al instalar react en ubuntu

Tags: reactjs

Hola buenas estoy iniciandome en esto de la programación y mi intención era dar un salto de calidad para crear webs mas bonitas. Decidí iniciar con react y como verán me sale los siguientes errores al instalar. Os digo que antes tenia zsh en vez de bash instalado y me daba error, asi que me desinstalado zsh, no se si tendrá algo que ver pero por si acaso lo comento. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no se ve el texto, copia el texto en lugar de imágenes

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema viene de que ese usuario no tiene permisos para instalarlo.

Solución:

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```